# How to enter recovery mode in a watch with one button (power)?

Tags: recovery-mode

I try to enter recovery mode in watch with one power button and no additional buttons , but failed to do that.

**Is it possible to enter recovery mode with this single button ?**

I try this with 2 different watch:
microwear H5,
kingwear 98

One of them is using android 5.1 , the other android 6.

Thank you

Comment: So you are talking about an Android Watch/Android Wear, right? You should also name your Android Watch model. From what I read the method is not the same for every device. BTW: Of course it is possible - the morse code also needs only one button and allows to transfer large texts - may be you should reformulate your question to "How to enter the recovery mode".

Comment: I've edited the message, it is a regular android, not android wear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that OP got an [answer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=76240664&postcount=37) from Xda-developers for Microwear H5.

> You can enter recovery mode via adb command or installing a reboot to recovery app from play store.

The adb command is the usual one for rebooting to recovery:

```
adb reboot recovery
```

The answer also applies for Kingwear KW98.